Trying to create a stored procedure in snowflake but unable to execute the procedure
I have created two tables Sales_Data and Vendor_type and a view Sales_Summary and a stored procedure.
When calling the query I am getting this error:

Error: 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 3 at position 4 : SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 8 (line 94)
invalid identifier 'SALES_ID'

Here are the SQL queries for creating tables, views, inserting data and stored procedures.
CREATE TABLE sales_data 
(
    sales_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    transaction_date DATE,
    transaction_time TIME,
    daily_id INT,
    first_name STRING,
    last_name STRING,
    email STRING,
    vendor_type STRING,
    cost DECIMAL(10, 2),
    cost_code STRING,
    cost_description STRING,
    sales_rep STRING,
    sale_state STRING,
    state_tax DECIMAL(5, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE vendor_info 
(
    vendor_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    vendor_name STRING,
    vendor_location STRING
);

CREATE VIEW sales_summary AS
SELECT 
    sd.sales_id,
    sd.transaction_date,
    sd.first_name,
    sd.last_name,
    sd.cost,
    sd.cost_description,
    vi.vendor_name
FROM 
    sales_data sd
JOIN 
    vendor_info vi ON sd.vendor_type = vi.vendor_name;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_sales_record
    (sales_id INT,
     transaction_date DATE,
     transaction_time TIME,
     daily_id INT,
     first_name STRING,
     last_name STRING,
     email STRING,
     vendor_type STRING,
     cost DECIMAL(10, 2),
     cost_code STRING,
     cost_description STRING,
     sales_rep STRING,
     sale_state STRING,
     state_tax DECIMAL(5, 2))
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sales_data VALUES (
        sales_id,
        transaction_date,
        transaction_time,
        daily_id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        email,
        vendor_type,
        cost,
        cost_code,
        cost_description,
        sales_rep,
        sale_state,
        state_tax
    );

    RETURN 'Record inserted successfully';
END;
$$;

CALL insert_sales_record(3, '2024-01-03', '11:00:00', 103, 'Mark', 'Smith', 'mark.smith@example.com', 'Retail', 200.00, 'C003', 'Home Goods', 'Charlie Johnson', 'NY', 10.00);


Specify the column names it may help. INSERT INTO sales_data (sales_id, trans.., ...) values(sales_id, trans..., ...);

You have to pass the parameter as identifier in SQL based stored Procedure in Snowflake based on its usage as variable or keyword used in query.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <db_nm>.<sc_nm>.test_proc
    (id string)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  <db_nm>.<sc_nm>.test_abc
    (id)
    VALUES 
    (
    -----------------------------------
    :id
    -----------------------------------
    );

    RETURN 'Record inserted successfully';
END;
$$;

call <db_nm>.<sc_nm>.test_proc('123');

as in the example you can see I have use :(colon) for identifier in the insert query.
